# Get ASP.NET temporary folder path

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

From my C# code, that doesn't run from within IIS/ASP.NET, I need to add a user account permissions to the ASP.NET temp folder. (It is required while adding my site to IIS.) The folder on my local system is:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

I'd hate to hard-code this path into my code, so I was wondering if I can retrieve it from .NET framework itself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hmm. I didn't know that it would be so complicated. For the lack of better answer, I was able to come up with something like this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

string net_base = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory(), @"..\.."));
string strTemp32 = string.Concat(net_base, @"\Framework\", RuntimeEnvironment.GetSystemVersion(), @"\Temporary ASP.NET Files");
string strTemp64 = string.Concat(net_base, @"\Framework64\", RuntimeEnvironment.GetSystemVersion(), @"\Temporary ASP.NET Files");
```

There're obviously two temp folders -- for 32-bit and 64-bit processes. It is based on [this sample](http://resnikb.wordpress.com/2009/05/21/installing-the-same-managed-addin-in-32bit-and-64bit-autodesk-inventor/), and also relies on the [assumption](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/457390-finding-asp-net-temporary-directory) that default ASP.NET temporary folders are `hard-coded`.

Correct me, if you find a better way?

Answer (score 10):

Try `System.Web.HttpRuntime.CodegenDir` to get the physical path of directory where the ASP.NET temporary files are stored for the current application.

Answer (score 5):

Simplest way with validation:

```
if (file.ContentLength > 0)
{
    string temp = Path.GetTempPath();

    var path = Path.Combine(temp, fileName);
    file.SaveAs(path);
}
```

and in web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation tempDirectory="D:\MyTempFiles" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: The top part wasn't necessary for me.  All I had to do was change the temp directory to see the compiled code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Much more safe will be if you use your own temporary folder in for example App_Data

Unfortunately `Path.GetTempPath();` won't return this folder because it is asp.net internal folder.

The good news is that you can change it specifing the file location in web.config with  element.

Comment: Thanks, that's one way. It'd be easier in my case though if I could deduce this temp path instead. While doing research now I found this path `%FrameworkInstallLocation%\Temporary ASP.NET Files` but I can't seem to expand it. Any idea how to do it? Here's the source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx

Comment: use this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6k3c7b0.aspx. Variable name is FrameworkIn stallLocation

Comment: Sorry, I just tried `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FrameworkInstallLocation")` and got `null`

Answer (score 2):

I think this should help...

There is a section in `web.config/machine.config` under the `compilation tag` where the path is set by default. Here are the attributes of the section...

[Documentation here](http://bit.ly/1fHJ4sl)

Comment: You see my C# code that needs this path doesn't run from under IIS. It runs as an elevated WinForm app, so I get, `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\ ` when I call `Path.GetTempPath()`

Comment: yes, that should return the User's temp path. I am going to delete my answer now. I was wrong. Why do you need the path anyway?

Comment: "From my C# code I need to add a user account permissions to the ASP.NET temp folder."

Comment: I'm writing one now. I can't do everything with a plain MSI.

Comment: It is set to "" by default. As Garath suggested below I can fill it out to some other folder. It won't give me that temp path though...