# Server configuration - MVC Web App causing C to run out of space on file upload

Tags: c#, iis, diskspace

Good morning all,
We have an MVC web application hosted on a server with two volumes: the C drive (which is perpetually under 1 GB of free space) and the D drive (which is where the inetpub is). The webapp root directory is on the D drive under inetpub, and when tested locally, when we upload these large files through the webapp, the files are saving successfully into the root of the web app (using HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath to get the running app path). However, on the server, we run out of space on C - when you initiate the file upload from the app, you can watch as C drive quickly runs out of space.

I'm not really too sure what could be causing this - if it's some sort of precache, or if IIS for some reason is running the server from the C drive somehow...has anyone else come across something like this and have any advice to bypass the C drive? I can't even find where the files are being saved or cached on C - I've checked all over the C drive and haven't found the files that get uploaded. It sounds like we aren't getting more space on the C drive as well, so that option is out.

Thanks!

Edit:
The C Drive had almost a whole 2 GB of free space this morning, so I went ahead and tested again. It does seem like it caches the file on C and then tries to move it over to D, as once the file is fully saved on C, it throws an error saying access is denied to d:/inetpub...

Comment: temp path maybe?  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129930/get-asp-net-temporary-folder-path  Something similar for this perhaps?

Comment: As an aside, I use a tool called OverDisk for looking into what's taking up space on drives.  I have no affiliation to it and it's free.  Shows things as a pie chart which you can drill into, so may help?

Comment: That's precisely what I want, thanks